# Turning on one PC causes another PC to boot up also

Tags: windows, printer, share

When a particular user logs into her Windows 7 PC (PC A) on my LAN, another Windows 7 PC (PC B) will turn on, if it isn’t turned on already.  The one thing these two PCs have in common is that PC B has a local USB-connected printer which is shared with PC A.  Could this be the reason for PC B’s boot?  How can I deactivate this?

Comment: The obvious question is: what happens if you unplug PC B from the USB printer? Either way, there may be an option in the BIOS if PC B called "Wake on LAN" which may be enabled. If so, disable it and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Disable WAKE-ON-LAN function in your BIOS/UEFI settings.
You can also disable other wakeup triggers like USB, mouse etc

Answer (score 1):

Some PC BIOS will have a setting to wake on mouse or keyboard activity.
Some will have wake on USB activity.

It's possible the printer, recognising PC A, will be interpreted as activity by PC B, and therefore wakes.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought... have you checked the back of the workstations and power cables to ensure they are not daisy chained? I.e. if booting PC A, the power pack will pass power to PC B and boot it up as well.